# Passing List as Parameter to java.lang.reflect.Method

Tags: java, generics

I have a method which looks like this;

```
public void update(List<Object> obj);
```

I want to be able to use **java.lang.reflect.Method** to invoke the method. Do anyone know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Class` class to get the method:

```
Class<?> clazz = theObject.getClass();
Method method = clazz.getMethod("update", List.class);
```

and then invoke the method:

```
method.invoke(theObject, new ArrayList<Object>());
```

Generics are erased at runtime. They're a compile-time thing. You may thus use `List.class` to refer to a `List<Object>`.

Comment: Quick question JB! - Say update(..) returned List how do you go about fetching the returned List<?> object?

Comment: You must cast the returned object to the desired (known) type: List<?> result = (List<?>) method.invoke(...)

Comment: Hmm! I am doing a exactly the same and empty value recieved. Have to investigate a bit further.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do

```
myObject.getClass()
    .getMethod("update", List.class)
    .invoke(myObject, myListOfObject);
```